# How to use bean in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

How to use bean in JSP with only `<jsp:useBean>`, not MVC?

Assume you have a `grade.txt` file which contains following data:

```
Tom 90
Jerry 70
Katy 80
John 60
```

It asks you to create a bean named `grade.java`, a JSP page named `graderesult.jsp`, and a html page named `gradecheck.html`.

`gradecheck.html` provides a input textbox and a button submit, once you submit the name of the student, the `graderesult.jsp` will communicates with bean to show the name and the score corresponding to the person.

Comment: Hi Nick. Welcome. I'd suggest rephrasing your question into an actual question. What are you having trouble with? If you just want someone to write all the code for you, you won't get very far.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `<jsp:setProperty name="beanname" property="*" />` to "automatically" set all request parameters as bean properties matching the property name. As this is a typical homework question, I won't give complete code examples, but only hints:

1. Create a bean `Grade` with a property `name`.
2. Add a constructor which loads the data from the text file into a `Map<String, Integer>` property representing name-score pairs. Learn more about Java IO [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) and about Java Maps [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).
3. Add a "special" getter `getScore()` which returns the score from the `Map` using the `name` as key.
4. Create a form with `<input type="text" name="name">` in the `gradecheck.html`. Let the form submit to `graderesult.jsp`. The request method doesn't matter, I would prefer `POST` though.
5. In the `graderesult.jsp` use `<jsp:useBean>` to declare and instantiate the bean in `request` scope and use `<jsp:setProperty>` to "automatically" set all input values in the bean.
6. Use EL to show the name by `${grade.name}` and the associated score by `${grade.score}`.

Good luck.